# Prevent standard user from changing encryption passphrase

Tags: permissions, encryption, passphrase

How do I prevent non root attempts by local user to change whole disk encryption passphrase of actual system in Ubuntu 20.04TLS.

Note that I removed my account from the sudoers list then restarted and yet there is no prompt for for root password.

The system is installed on an SD card.

Comment: Which encryption passphase?

Comment: System whole disk encryption

Comment: And what testing did you do to determine that a non-root user can change that passphrase?

Comment: Does the user have physical access to the computer? Lock out the user's account. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Yes I want to block physical user access to change the encryption password using the graphical app Disks without locking local user account.

Comment: Is the user account an admin account with sudo access?

Comment: @heynnema I removed my account from the sudoers list and yet there's no prompt for root password, and I can change the passphrase without password. I think I have to block the script to be executed by root only still I don't know exactly what script and I don't want to break the system. Do you have an idea how I can do so ? Or if there is another solution for the issue ?

Comment: Did you set a root password? I don't know how to help any further. Hopefully somebody else will chime in with a better solution.

Comment: Check contents of /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d/ to see if your user is configured to sudo without a password.

Comment: @user10489 the local user is denied sudo privileges, when I try to unlock the SATA HARD DRIVE where my other system :Debian is installed it does ask for password but when I try to  change the passphrase  on the SD card where my active system is installed it doesn't ask for password.

Comment: So I think it's I have to activate password protection for the SD card.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using that you are using to change the disk password?